# How can I make a scrolling background in sprite kit

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

I am making a iOS game using SpriteKit. I am using the following code to populate my background so it scrolls seamlessly.

```
static const float BG_VELOCITY = 100.0;
static inline CGPoint CGPointAdd(const CGPoint a, const CGPoint b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y);
}

static inline CGPoint CGPointMultiplyScalar(const CGPoint a, const CGFloat b)
{
    return CGPointMake(a.x * b, a.y * b);
}



-(void)initalizingScrollingBackground
{
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    SKSpriteNode *bg = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"bg"];
    bg.position = CGPointMake(i * bg.size.width, 0);
    bg.anchorPoint = CGPointZero;
    bg.name = @"bg";
    [self addChild:bg];
}
}
```

I get the scrolling feature, but then when the two backgrounds "connect", there is a "white space lag" like the pictures shown below:

[image: IMG]

[image: IMG]

Comment: I just found out this problem only occurs in iPhone 6 and PLUS. FPS is at 15 using the PLUS while it is 30 in the 6. iPhone 5s/5/4s has no issue mentioned above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
-(void)update:(NSTimeInterval)currentTime {
    if(!_paused){
        if (_lastUpdateTime) {
            _deltaTime = currentTime - _lastUpdateTime;
        } else {
            _deltaTime = 0;
        }
        _lastUpdateTime = currentTime;
        //change this if you want to scroll horizontally or vertically (now horizontally)
        CGPoint bgVelocity = CGPointMake(_pointsPerSecondSpeed,0.0);
        CGPoint amtToMove = CGPointMake(bgVelocity.x * _deltaTime, bgVelocity.y * _deltaTime);

        _moved = CGPointMake(_moved.x + amtToMove.x, _moved.y + amtToMove.y);

        [self enumerateChildNodesWithName:@"bg" usingBlock: ^(SKNode *node, BOOL *stop) {
            SKSpriteNode *bg = (SKSpriteNode *) node;
            bg.position = CGPointMake(bg.position.x+amtToMove.x, bg.position.y+amtToMove.y);

        }];
    }
}
```

You have to factor the time in your scrolling code. That way the animation is smooth

Make two @property _lastUpdateTime and _pointsPerSecondSpeed in .h file.

Initialize the _pointsPerSecondSpeed with 5 and check if it is scrolling smoothly.

Increase this until you are happy.